# Unable to upgrade storage account from v1 to StorageV2

Tags: azure, azure-storage

**Requirement:** Upgrade Storage account from V(Storage kind) to V2(StorageV2)

**Current skuName:** Standard_ZRS

**Command used:**

```
Set-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName <RG> -AccountName <Storage account name> -SkuName Standard_ZRS -EnableHttpsTrafficOnly:$true -UpgradeToStorageV2 -AccessTier Hot
```

Location: UK South

**Error code**
InvalidValuesForRequestParameters
**Message**
Values for request parameters are invalid: sku.

The Location of storage account is UK South and already have a container deployed in it.

Answer (score 0):

Just try without the parameters,

```
Set-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -AccountName $storageAccount -UpgradeToStorageV2
```

then set the Access Tier

Comment: Let me try this and update back if this works! .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in the portal that does this for you, I used it a few months back but can't remember where on the storage blade it is but it's definitely there as I originally planned to use PowerShell then by the time I got to it the UI feature appeared and worked flawlessly.

Here you go https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-upgrade?tabs=azure-portal